# How to communicate between two apps without using App Groups?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios-app-group

I need to create an app(app2) that will communicate with my host app:

app2 needs to change the color background of the cells in the host app.

I need to find a way to send data from app2 to the host app with the `UICollectionView`.

**Please notice:**

1. I can not use App Groups.
2. I can not change properties of the host app (for example inside the 
   info plist by adding URL Schemes)

Comment: If you can't change your host app you're out of luck, afaik.

Comment: then its not possible in iOS at least.